# Why is the Fourier transform called a 'transform', and not a 'transformation'?

Tags: linear-transformations, terminology, integral-transforms

Why are the Hilbert Transform, Fourier transform, Laplace Transform, etc called transforms, and not transformations?

This is about linguistics or terminology in mathematics. I feel there should be a reason why the word 'transform' used for such mathematical objects.

Is 'transform' as a noun, an invented word (coined word) for mathematics?

I have to name a concept in the context of functional programming, and want to know which name is suitable for it:

transform, transformation, map, homeomorphism, morphism, etc.

I want this term to be defendable for people in management and BAs (which are not Mathematicians).

PS. (After [Blazej](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155834/blazej)'s answer): My supervisor used to correct me to use "Hilbert Transform" and to avoid using the word transformation for Hilbert Transform (HT). Also the [wikipedia page for HT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) uses the word "transform" for the HT's operator, and not its output.

Answer (score 4):

I think operation which assigns to the function $x \mapsto f(x)$ another function $p \mapsto \int f(x) e^{-ipx} dx = \widetilde {f}(p)$ should be called Fourier transformation, as you suggest. On the other hand the result of this operation, i.e. the function $\widetilde f$, is called the Fourier transform (a noun) of $f$.

Comment: So, is this word coined only to distinguish two different meaning that you described? Is it a linguistic derivative to create a noun from the verb 'transforming'? My question is perhaps more about linguistics: transformation is also a noun created from a verb.

Comment: Your answer seems the best answer so far. But I have a problem here: My supervisor used to correct me Hilbert Transform (HT) and to avoid using the word transformation for HT. Also the wikipedia uses the word "transform" for the operator, and not the output.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform .  What do you think? I am adding HT to the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is 'transform' as a noun, an invented word (coined word) for mathematics?

Apparently so.  The *Oxford English Dictionary* has "transform" (noun) first used by Sylvester in 1853.

> SYLVESTER in *Philos. Trans.* (Royal Soc.) **143** i. 544   *Covariant*, a function which stands in the same relation to the primitive function from which it is derived as any of its linear transforms do to a similarly derived transform of its primitive.

Since 1965, "transform" (noun) is also used in geology.

Comment: Why was that word used by Sylvester? and from which context is it borrowed? Perhaps geology?

Comment: Etymology: *transform* (noun) comes from *transform* (verb).